# Continuity of a homotopy on infinite simplicial complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory, simplicial-complex

> [Proposition2.2 (ncatlab):](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+approximation+theorem) Suppose $\phi: X \to Y$ is a simplicial approximation to a map $f: {|X|} \to {|Y|}$, and suppose $f = {|\phi|}$ on a subset $A \subseteq {|X|}$. Then there is a homotopy ${|\phi|} \simeq f \; rel \; A$.
>
> *Proof* Define the homotopy $H$ by $H(\alpha, t) = t f(\alpha) + (1-t){|\phi|}(\alpha)$. This makes sense since if $f(\alpha) \in {|s|}$, then ${|\phi|}(\alpha) \in {|s|}$ and ${|s|}$ is closed under convex combinations. Clearly $H(\alpha, t) = f(\alpha)$ for all $t$ on a set where $f$ and ${|\phi|}$ agree.

I see why if $|Y| \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ the homotopy $H$ is continuous as $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a topological vector space. But this need not be the case in general? What if $Y$ is an infinite dimensional simplicial complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check $H$ is continuous, you only need to check that it is continuous on $\sigma\times I$ for each finite simplex $\sigma\subseteq |X|$.  But any such $\sigma\times I$ is compact, and so the images of $f$ and $|\phi|$ on $\sigma$ are contained in a finite subcomplex of $|Y|$.  The image of $H$ on $\sigma\times I$ will then be contained in that finite subcomplex, so to check its continuity you may assume $Y$ is finite.

Comment: Sorry, but why are they contained in a finite subcomplex of $|Y|$?  I know this holds for CW complexes as they have the locally finite condition, but is this true too for simplicial complexes?

Comment: Simplicial complexes are a special type of CW complex.  (The topology on an infinite simplicial complex is defined as the weak topology for its simplices.)

Comment: Is there a source where I can reference that simplicial complex is a special type of CW complex? I can give a CW complex structure to finite simplicial complexes, but not infinite simplicial complexes (using the general definition given in wikipedia).

Comment: I'm not sure what your difficulty is.  The CW structure for infinite simplicial complexes is exactly the same as for finite simplicial complexes: the cells of the CW structure are the simplices.

Comment: My difficulty is I don't see why this structure satisfies closure finiteness.

Comment: That's trivial: any simplex has only finitely many simplices of lower dimension that are in its boundary (since every such lower-dimensional simplex corresponds to some subset of its vertices).

Comment: Ah, i was interpreting closure finiteness wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: if you have time do you mind looking at this ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521816/exercise-rotman-8-33-algebraic-topology-cw-complex-structure